# How to stop jDeveloper from regenerating .jpr files

Tags: ide, jdeveloper

I use GIT and what I constantly see is that git shows that entire SomeModel.jpr contents were removed and replaced with the same contents. File stays the same. Well sometimes something changes and you miss it in whole soup. 
Build JDEVADF_11.1.2.3.0_GENERIC_120914.0223.6276.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably a problem with your git configuration. I saw this to when I worked on a Windows system and git is configured to use only line feed as line terminator. Check your git settings and play with the line terminator settings (auto or leave as is).